# Fugitive Gbrowse while being ssh on a server

Tags: tmux, plugin-fugitive, ssh

I work remotely via ssh on my dev machine which runs a tmux. I want to pipe the output of the Gbrowse back to my laptop. Is there any reasonable way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Gbrowse!` to get the url copied into the clipboard and then either paste it in the local browser or fire another `:!ssh` command from the remote machine to the local machine, like (from `vim` in the ssh session)

```
:Gbrowse! | exe "!ssh $LOCAL 'nohup google-chrome " . @+ . "' &"
```

change `google-chrome` to other browsers or `xdg-open` to use the default if you are in ubuntu.